# Js-ctypes third part dll with string return

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, jsctypes

I am using a DLL with js-ctypes that is made in C.

The method return a string, but when I try access the content of the pointer firefox crashes!

**The following code works:**

*Function declaration:*

```
var getStr = lib.declare("getString", 
            ctypes.default_abi,
            ctypes.char.ptr,
            ctypes.int32_t
            );
```

*Function call:*

```
let number = new ctypes.int32_t(1);
var str = getStr(number);
console.log(str.toString());
str.readString();
```

The `console.log` output's:

```
ctypes.char.ptr(ctypes.UInt64("0x64ff5b48"))
```

**But this code don't work:**

*Function declaration:*

```
var Core = {
    init : function(){
        this.lib = ctypes.open("library");
        this.getStr = this.lib.declare("getString",
                                       ctypes.default_abi,
                                       ctypes.char.ptr,
                                       ctypes.int32_t);
    },

    close : function(){
        this.lib.close();
    }

}
```

*Function call*

```
Core.init();
var number = new ctypes.int32_t(1);
var result = Core.getStr(number);
console.log(result.toString());
result.readString();
```

The `console.log` output's:

```
ctypes.char.ptr(ctypes.UInt64("0x64ff5b48"))
```

The same thing !

With this way firefox crashes. Anyone know how to solve this? I was doing this way for modulation of the addon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem! Thank you Noitidart. In the second example I was closing the library before the `str.readString()`. It makes firefox crash. I tried to reduce the code on the question post and forgot about this detail, I am sorry.

Comment: Nice find :) I didn't know readString would crash if library was closed, thats interesting thanks for sharing.

Comment: I had the same problem, but instead, it happened because my native code was freeing the string before JS read it.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting `str` to known length like this: `var strCasted = ctypes.cast(str, ctypes.char.array(100).ptr);`  then try reading string like this: `var jsStr = strCasted.contents.readString();` that should do the trick if not jump on #jsctypes moz channel we'll discuss it then update back here with the solution. Paste this to your url bar: irc://moznet/jsctypes

This tutorial on casting should help: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/081ef49002a90fe43005#comment-1470308

Comment: Thank you Noitidart. I am sorry, please check my question again after the edit. Now all the code is there and I found what is making firefox crash, but I don't know how to solve.

Comment: @Sabbathman btw can you tell me in your working and non-working code what is `str.toString()` im curious, thanks

Comment: Oh you have to do the `.toString()` before doing `.readString()` as the crash happens at readString

Comment: kkkkk I am using a fiscal printer DLL. I can't do `str.toString().readString()` because after this my object is not of type CData and don't have the method `readString()`

Comment: Oh no toString.readString after the toString thats very wrrong, dont do any readStrings to get the toString stuff for debug. I just need the str.toString() in both instances to see whats up.

Comment: Ooh check the question again please. The str.toString() it is equal in both cases.